# efficiently calculate cosine similarity between vector shape (768,) and matrix (n, 768)

Tags: python, numpy

i have following target embeddings vector `u` shape of `(768,)` and target embeddings matrix `v` shape of `(23, 768)`. I need to calculate cosine similarity between target vector and matrix. I know how to do it in cycle:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

for i in v:
   cosine_similarity(u.reshape(-1, 1), i.reshape(-1,1))[0][0]
```

But how to do it like numpy way ? My target is to have array of cosine similarities like

```
array[0.4, 0.5, 0.6, ... n]
```

Comment: Simpler `cosine_similarity([u], v)` or faster `u.dot(v.T) / (np.linalg.norm(u) * np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i', v, v)))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
u = np.random.random(768)
v = np.random.random((23,768))
w = np.array([u.dot(v[i])/(np.linalg.norm(u)*np.linalg.norm(v[i])) for i in range(23)])
print(w)
```